# Casting Nested Generic Types

Tags: java, generics

I understand that it is illegal in Java to cast a `List<Number>` to a `List<Double>`, since `List<Double>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>`:

```
    List<Number> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> list2 = (List<Double>) list1;  // inconvertible types
```

With this understanding I would expect that it is also illegal to cast a `List<? extends List<Number>>` to a `List<List<Double>>`, since I would think that `List<Double>` does not belong to the family of types given by `List<Number>`.  However, this cast is actually valid, with an unchecked cast warning:

```
    List<? extends List<Number>> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<List<Double>> list4 = (List<List<Double>>) list3;  // unchecked cast warning, but legal
```

How can I go about reasoning that `List<Double>` belongs to the family of types given by `List<Number>`, when the first cast above is illegal?

Using javac 1.8.0_144 in Intellij:

[image: illegal]

Comment: Check the concept of covariance and contravariance in java. This article may be helpful:
https://dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: `List<Double>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>`, so we know that a `List<? extends List<Number>>` definitely is not a `List<List<Double>>`.  A cast from the former type to the latter type can, in principle, be proved incorrect at compile time.  Either your compiler fails to recognize that, or it just chooses to warn instead of issuing an error.  Possibly that constitutes a compiler bug.

Comment: ha? what `javac` version?

Comment: @Eugene this is using javac 1.8.0_144.  Added a screenshot of the unchecked cast warning.

Comment: this _isn't_ `javac`. try to compile the same thing from your terminal.

Comment: did the answer help you, btw?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what tool you are using to compile this, but I have not found one `jdk` that compile this, from `8` to `16`.

This is illegal:

```
List<? extends List<Number>> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<Double>> list4 = (List<List<Double>>) list3;
```

for obvious reasons. `? extends List<Number` can't possibly be a super-type of `List<Double>`.